# Navigation action cannot be found although it exists

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a fragment Setup with a button that navigates to a fragment Scanner when the button is pressed. The Scanner fragment should navigate back to Scanner passing the output of an image analyzer (QR code).

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scanner, container, false)

    var previewView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.previewView)
    cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this.context!!)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        bindPreview(cameraProvider, view) {
            val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putString("param1", p1)
                putString("param2", p2)
            }
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_scanner_to_setup, bundle)            }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this.context!!) )

    return view
}
```

I have set the action from Scanner to Setup properly, in fact it works if I attempt to navigate() outside of that Runnable block.

[image: Nav graph and error]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add navigation either inside

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            //Here
        }
```

Or if you can get activity

```
this.runOnUiThread {
     //Here
}
```

Comment: Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post... did it - thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad it helped:)